# Wordpress equivalent for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, content-management-system

I do not know anything about PHP or Wordpress. But I was told Wordpress is very cool to use with PHP.

I use ASP.NET and would like to have a CMS for ASP.NET.

What is the best CMS to use for ASP.NET when cost is not an issue?

Comment: The best CMS? Be a little more constructive please.

Comment: which ones have you looked at already? What are your requirements? 

But to give you a direction, you could look into Umbraco.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Orchard](http://orchardproject.net/), it's based on ASP.NET MVC